# Using D3.js to create a simple treemap

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have some csv data that I count the occurences of each item to get an array of integers representing the count of each distinct item. I want to use D3.js v5 to create a treemap where the size of each rectangle is proportional to these numbers. All resources on treemaps I have seen use hierarchies and trees to create this. Is it possible to create a very basic treemap using only numbers representing areas?

Like this:
[Treemap example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcmLd.png)

Comment: Please post a picture of the desired result, it can help...

Comment: Post is edited with an example image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample:

```js
const data = [300, 200, 150, 100, 50].sort((a,b) => b - a);
const sum = data.reduce((s, i) => s + i, 0);

const svg = d3.select('svg');
const width = parseInt(svg.attr('width'));
const height = parseInt(svg.attr('height'));
const unit = width * height / sum;
const bounds = {top: 0, left: 0, right: width, bottom: height}; 

let weightLeft = sum;
let x, y, w, h;

data.forEach(d => {
  const hSpace = bounds.right - bounds.left;
  const vSpace = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;
  const area = d / unit;
  x = bounds.left;
  y = bounds.top;
  if (hSpace > vSpace) {
    w = (d / weightLeft) * hSpace;
    h = vSpace;
    bounds.left = x + w;
  }
  else {
    w = hSpace;
    h = (d / weightLeft) * vSpace;
    bounds.top = y + h;
  }
  weightLeft -= d;
  svg.append('rect')
    .attr('x', x)
    .attr('y', y)
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h)
    .style('fill', 'blue')
    .style('stroke', 'white')
    .style('stroke-width', 3)
  svg.append('text')
    .text(d)
    .attr('x', x + w/2)
    .attr('y', y + h/2)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
    .style('fill', 'white')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="250" height="200" />
```